Chainlink Functions "sender not allowlisted" error
const { SecretsManager } = require("@chainlink/functions-toolkit");
const ethers = require("ethers");

const uploadSecrets = async () => {
  // hardcoded for Sepolia
  const routerAddress = "0xb83E47C2bC239B3bf370bc41e1459A34b41238D0";
  const donId = "fun-ethereum-sepolia-1";
  const gatewayUrls = [
    "https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/",
    "https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/",
  ];

  // Initialize ethers signer and provider to interact with the contracts onchain
  const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY; // fetch PRIVATE_KEY
  if (!privateKey)
    throw new Error(
      "private key not provided - check your environment variables"
    );

  const rpcUrl = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL;

  if (!rpcUrl)
    throw new Error(`rpcUrl not provided  - check your environment variables`);

  const secrets = {
    alpacaKey: process.env.ALPACA_API_KEY ?? "",
    alpacaSecret: process.env.ALPACA_SECRET_KEY ?? "",
  };
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcUrl);
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
  const signer = wallet.connect(provider); // create ethers signer for signing transactions

  // First encrypt secrets and upload the encrypted secrets to the DON
  const secretsManager = new SecretsManager({
    signer: signer,
    functionsRouterAddress: routerAddress,
    donId: donId,
  });
  await secretsManager.initialize();

  // Encrypt secrets and upload to DON
  const encryptedSecretsObj = await secretsManager.encryptSecrets(secrets);
  const slotIdNumber = 0; // slot ID where to upload the secrets
  const expirationTimeMinutes = 1440; // expiration time in minutes of the secrets, 1440 is 1 day

  console.log(
    `Upload encrypted secret to gateways ${gatewayUrls}. slotId ${slotIdNumber}. Expiration in minutes: ${expirationTimeMinutes}`
  );
  // Upload secrets
  const uploadResult = await secretsManager.uploadEncryptedSecretsToDON({
    encryptedSecretsHexstring: encryptedSecretsObj.encryptedSecrets,
    gatewayUrls: gatewayUrls,
    slotId: slotIdNumber,
    minutesUntilExpiration: expirationTimeMinutes,
  });

  if (!uploadResult.success)
    throw new Error(`Encrypted secrets not uploaded to ${gatewayUrls}`);

  console.log(
    `\n✅ Secrets uploaded properly to gateways ${gatewayUrls}! Gateways response: `,
    uploadResult
  );

  const donHostedSecretsVersion = parseInt(uploadResult.version); // fetch the reference of the encrypted secrets
  console.log(`\n✅ Secrets version: ${donHostedSecretsVersion}`);
};

uploadSecrets().catch((e) => {
  console.error(e);
  process.exit(1);
});

This is the file through which I am providing my secrets env to the DON.
But I keep on getting this error:
Upload encrypted secret to gateways https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/,https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/. slotId 0. Expiration in minutes: 1440
Error encountered when attempting to send request to DON gateway URL #1 of 2
https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"3538047860","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"sender not allowlisted"}}
Error encountered when attempting to send request to DON gateway URL #2 of 2
https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1183972950","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"sender not allowlisted"}}
Error: Failed to send request to any of the DON gateway URLs:
["https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/","https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/"]
    at SecretsManager.sendMessageToGateways (/home/sarthak/Blockchain/Tesla Stock Tokenization/node_modules/@chainlink/functions-toolkit/dist/SecretsManager.js:214:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SecretsManager.uploadEncryptedSecretsToDON (/home/sarthak/Blockchain/Tesla Stock Tokenization/node_modules/@chainlink/functions-toolkit/dist/SecretsManager.js:155:33)
    at async uploadSecrets (/home/sarthak/Blockchain/Tesla Stock Tokenization/functions/uploadSecrets.js:50:24)


Did you replace the consumer contract address and the subscription ID with your own values?
See step 2 of 'To run the example:'
https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/tutorials/api-use-secrets

I had the same issue, you need to first go on Chainlink Functions Manager and create a subscription with the account you're using to upload secrets. You can add your consumer later on, but it will allow you to upload your secrets.
Hope that helps !
